# installing linux-headers-standard on Ubuntu 20.04 / WSL2

Tags: apt, 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, linux-headers

When I use VBoxManage to create a vm I'm told I need to have linux-headers-generic installed. So I try `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-standard` and get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-standard
```

https://www.tecmint.com/install-kernel-headers-in-ubuntu-and-debian/ presents another way to do this:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. Here's what I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.19.128-microsoft-standard
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.19.128-microsoft-standard'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, the base WSL2 kernel does not allow modules to be loaded. You will need to compile and use your own kernel build 

Comment: And to do that, you'll need the Microsoft patches to the kernel, which you can check out [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel).

Comment: Also note that you would need a recent Windows build for Intel nested virtualization (needed to run VirtualBox under Hyper-V, which is used for WSL2) or Windows Insider/Preview if you have an AMD CPU.  Even then, it will likely require changes to VirtualBox.  [This](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/relnotes/nested-virt-support.html) makes it sound like the VirtualBox nested virtualization support may only be for running other hypervisors *under* VirtualBox, rather than the other way around. Just not sure whether it will work even after you jump through the kernel hoops.

Comment: even i went through this. ```https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/releases/tag/linux-msft-wsl-5.15.90.1``` this might help you.